# RAM frequency for Broadwell E processors

Tags: memory

It looks like all current Broadwell E processors support DDR4-2400 while the motherboard I'm considering apparently supports up to DDR4-3333.

Does it mean that buying 3333MHz memory is a waste of money because the processor will drive it at 2400MHz? What if the processor is over clocked? Does it have any effect?